# How to find mean for 2 x 2 design with time series data using dplyr/aggregate in R

Tags: r, time, dplyr, aggregate

Here is the data:

```
stage <- c("bluemale", "bluefemale", "redmale", "redfemale","bluemale", "bluefemale", "redmale", "redfemale","bluemale", "bluefemale", "redmale", "redfemale","bluemale", "bluefemale", "redmale", "redfemale","bluemale", "bluefemale", "redmale", "redfemale","bluemale", "bluefemale", "redmale", "redfemale","bluemale", "bluefemale", "redmale", "redfemale","bluemale", "bluefemale", "redmale", "redfemale")
rep <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8)
treatment <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
T1 <- runif(32,0,100)
T2 <- runif(32,0,100)
T3 <- runif(32,0,100)
T4 <- runif(32,0,100)
T100 <- runif(32,0,100)
stage <- as.factor(stage)
rep <- as.factor(rep)
treatment <- as.factor(treatment)

dat <- data.frame(stage,rep,treatment,T1,T2,T3,T4,T100)
```

There are two replicates for every treatment type.

1. I need to add blue = (bluemale, bluefemale) and red = (redmale, redfemale), average it for one replicate.
2. Take the average across replicates and treatments. This needs to be done for each time point.

In the end, I need 2 rows for every treatment. 4 treatments, 2 rows each with "blue" and "red". The T1..T100 represent the average across replicates.

```
new_stage  treatment T1 T2 T3 T4
blue        1         5  41 4  5 
red         1        33  2 3   4
blue        2        12  1  2  4
red         2        44  22 1  8
blue        3         5  41 4  5 
red         3        33  2  3  4
blue        4        12  1  2  4
red         4        44  22 1  8
```

The "big" goal is to see blues = bluemale+bluefemale, and reds = redmale+redfemale across time for the 4 treatments.

I am not sure how to do (1) i.e. the adding of bluemale+bluefemale part. 
But here is my attempt for the part (2):

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(rep,treatment) %>% 
  summarise(all_average = mean(dat[4:8,]))

Output that says all_average is NA. Warning argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

If someone knows how this can be achieved using aggregate function, that would be useful.

Comment: You are creating a `matrix` and not a `data.frame`.  Use `data.frame` instead of `cbind`.  Also, it is not clear about your expected output.  Do you need `dat %>% group_by(rep, treatment) %>% summarise_at(vars(matches("^T\\d+")), mean)`

Comment: I hope I have made the question clearer. This code does help, but prior to this I need to add males and females of each colour together. In the end, I need 2 rows for every treatment. 4 treatments, 2 rows each with "blue" and "red"

Comment: If you can, please add the expected output by editing the post.  Also, use `set.seed` to make the example reproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited as per the comments. Now for part 1., there is only one tow for each treatment with T's replaced by the averages.

```
df <- dat %>%
  mutate(stage = recode(stage, 
                        bluemale = "blue",
                        bluefemale = "blue",
                        redmale = "red",
                        redfemale = "red")
  ) 

subdf <- subset(df, select = -c(stage, rep, treatment))

aggregate(subdf, 
          list(treatment = df$treatment), mean)
```

For part 2,  fixing your code.

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(rep, treatment) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(T1:T100), funs(mean))
```

If the you need to keep the stage as well;

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(stage, rep, treatment) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(T1:T100), funs(sum))
```

Comment: 1. I need to average it over the replicates. So that I have only 1 set of values from that treatment (see edited, expected output).

Comment: Also, I am unclear as to the difference between chunk 2 and chunk 3

Comment: Also, in my original data set I have 100 columns of time points. So is there an easier way to write `mutate(T1 = sum(T1), T2 = sum(T2), T3 = sum(T3),
         T4 = sum(T4), T100 = sum(T100))`

Comment: > unclear as to the difference between chunk 2 and chunk 3: did you run them as see the difference. First one ignores the "stage" variable

Comment: I apologize. I had not logged in for a while and was still troubleshooting. This help. Thanks!